# Unable to repartition non-mounted SD card

Tags: partitioning, mount, sd-card

I have a 64GB SD card which I'm trying to use for a Raspberry Pi. I've had some issues with it so I want to wipe it and start over. In order to do that I want to create a single FAT32-formatted partition on sdb.

`sudo fdisk /dev/sdb` appears to work fine up until the final `w` at which point it informs me:

> The partition table has been altered.
>
> Calling ioctl() to re-read the partition table.
>
> Re-reading the partition table failed.: Device or resource busy
>
> The kernel still uses the old table. The new table will be used at the next reboot or after you run partprobe(8) or kpartx(8).

I also tried `sufo cfdisk /dev/sdb`, which appeared to work - but when I used gparted the GUI says that the File System is "unknown". If I attempt to use gparted to format it to FAT32, I get an error message:

> Libparted Error
>
> Partition(s) 1, 2 on /dev/sdb have been written, but we have been unable to inform the kernel of the change, probably because it/they are in use.  As a result, the old partition(s) will remain in use.  You should reboot now before making further changes

Clicking ignore on that message aborts the operation.

The output of `umount /dev/sdb` is `umount: /dev/sdb: not mounted`

I'm at a loss. What can I do to to format and repartition this SD?

Comment: Use `sudo partprobe /dev/sdb` to "inform the OS of partition table changes". For reference: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/partprobe.8.html

Comment: Are you a wizard???? Please move this to an answer and I'll mark it as accepted. I ran that and suddenly gparted works

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `sudo partprobe /dev/sdb` to "inform the OS of partition table changes".

For more info, check `man partprobe` or http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/partprobe.8.html.